# Simulation problem - inverse transform method not succeding

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, simulation

Suppose 1 and 2 are i.i.d. (0,1). What's the distribution of
− (1/3) ln(1) − (1/3) ln(1 − 2)?

I tried to solve this problem using inverse transform method but it did not lead me an answer. Can any one find a solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean by " if it is simulation or probability"?

Comment: I was not going to say that and thought I deleted that. I am sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

If $U_2$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and independent of $U_1$, then so is $1-U_2$. Thus you are adding two independent random variables of the form $-\frac13\ln U$ with $U$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. These have [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Generating_exponential_variates) with parameter $3$. The sum of two exponential variables with the same rate parameter has [Erlang distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution) with shape parameter $2$ and rate parameter given by the parameter of the exponential variables (in this case $3$).

Comment: Dont I have two different variables, so I find them exponential distrubitons with -3y and -3z parameters. They have different variables, How can I add them together properly

Comment: @SerkanGöktaş: Sorry, that makes no sense to me. What do $-3y$ and $-3z$ mean? There's nothing like that in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I just wrote them by myself when solving. I just wonder that they are two different variables as U1 and U2. So how can I integrated them into question properly? F(x1)= 1-e^(-3x1). I wrote them like that. The other one is with x2. So how can I add two of them together.

Comment: @SerkanGöktaş: But I wrote that in the answer? "The sum of two exponential variables with the same rate parameter has Erlang distribution ...". Did you follow that link?

Comment: At first I did not understand the content of the link but after hours of work, I could finally understand. Thank you so much for your help.